# Why was restoring a dead lipo battery possible?

Tags: batteries, lipo

Have been charging completely dead and inflated Lipo batteries (no longer fit for use)individually outside the balancer. Charged with CC/CV following the limits set in the datasheet. This ofcourse with all the preventive measures in case something went wrong. The temperature remained at room temperature.
After completing the charging cycle the inflation was gone and after connecting the batteries back to the balancer everything seems to work correctly. The standard charger works again and the batteries show a normal behavior under load.
I wonder why this was possible?

Comment: I wonder too. I still wouldn't trust it in my house though. I guess this is just an academic exercise?

Comment: Sounds like a miracle to me :)

Comment: For the moment just academic and stored in a place without danger.

Comment: Measure capacity and internal series resistance. Compare with a new cell. Most likely the anode has been degraded, and increased series resistance and decreased capacity.